# Create custom UI elements in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to draw customized elements on a JFrame.

I've tried it by creating a class UI (extends JFrame) and a class Component (extends JPanel). The component draws something on itself and the UI just adds this component. So until now, I've written this code:

File UI.java

```
package UIComponent;

import javax.swing.JFrame; 

public class UI extends JFrame {

    public UI(){
        this.setSize(1024,684);
        this.setTitle("This is just a test program."); 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.add(new Component(20,20,20,20)); 
        this.add(new Component(40,30,20,20)); 
    }

}
```

File Component.java

```
package UIComponent;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 

public class Component extends JPanel {

    int x, y, w, h; 

    public Component(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
        this.w = w; 
        this.h = h; 
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }

}
```

But the result is not that what I accept. It draws just one Rectangle.

Comment: "But the result is not that what I accept. It draws just one Rectangle." - What IS the result you want. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x/y/w/h values have no bearing on the actual size of the compnent  which is likely to be 0x0, meaning that you'd be painting out side of the visible area of the component.

Start by overriding the `getPreferredSize` method and return a area which would allow you painting to be visible, something like....

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(x + w, y + h);
}
```

For example.

JFrame uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which means that it will only allow one component to be visible within any of its 5 available positions.

This means that your example will only show the last component added.

Depending on what you intend to achieve, you might consider using an `OverlayLayout` or some other layout manager.

Personally, unless you had a particular need, I would not worry about the x/y position of the painting, and simply paint from the 0x0 position of component, allowing the containers layout manager to deal with the actually positing.

I'd as reconsider some of your naming, as Component already exists in the API and may cause confusion, and components already have a concept of position and size...

Remember, the position of the component within its container has no effect on where the components drawing starts. That is, 0x0 is always the top left corner of the component.

Answer (score 2):

Don't extend JFrame. You are not adding any new behaviour to the frame.

Don't call your class Component. There is already an AWT class by that name so you will probably cause Swing to stop working.

```
this.add(new Component(20,20,20,20)); 
this.add(new Component(40,30,20,20));
```

The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. By default when you add components to the frame without specifying a constraint they go to the CENTER. The CENTER can only contain a single component, so that is why you only see the last one added.

Instead try adding one component to the BorderLayout.NORTH and one to the SOUTH.

Also, the components won't paint properly because you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of you custom component so the layout manager can do its job:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(w, h);
}
```

Also, the paintComponent() method should invoke `super.paintComonent()`.

Check out the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You should be reading the sections on `Custom Painting` and `Layout Managers` for more information.

Also, the painting of your rectangles should be done at an x/y location of (0, 0) so that the entire painting will fit in the width/height of your component. If you want the rectangle to appear at a specific location then you should be using a null layout in which case you are responsible for setting the location and size of the component.

If you are trying to just paint shapes on a panel then you should probably be playing with the `Shape` class instead of creating custom components. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more ideas.

Comment: The AWT class is called `java.awt.Component`. The OP's class is called `UIComponent.Component`. There is no conflict that would "probably cause Swing to stop working", but the similar names could cause confusion, or require them to be fully qualified if they were used in the same code.

Comment: @DavidConrad, good point, I missed the package name. Anyway I think my point is made that using an existing JDK class name causes unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a LayoutManager should give your the two rectangles you're looking for

```
public class UI extends JFrame {

    public UI(){
        this.setSize(1024,684);
        this.setTitle("This is just a test program."); 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.add(new GridLayout(1, 2));  // I used a simple grid layout.
        this.add(new Component(20,20,20,20)); 
        this.add(new Component(40,30,20,20)); 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       SwingUtlities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               new UI();
           }
       });
   }
```

}

Comment: While a good suggestion, considering the default, preferred size of a component is normally 0x0, this will have little effect. Also, considering the fact that the OP is painting beyond the normal visible area of the component, unless they actually resize the window, this will have little effect...

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. Short question: What is the SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable...)-Method for?

Comment: @user2989330 Take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details. Basically, when a JVM starts your class, it is running within, what's known as, the main thread.  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` ensures that you start your UI within the context of the EDT